# How do I make a summary and then multiply the result by group?

Tags: r, sum, multiplication, weighted

So this is my data frame. Country1 represent the people that live in Germany and Country 2 represent the country that they used to live 5 years before moving to Country1 .

| Country1 | Country2 | Weight | obs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | Germany | 4 | 1 |
| Germany | Germany | 119 | 2 |
| France | Germany | 3 | 3 |
| France | Germany | 2 | 4 |
| Italy | France | 1 | 5 |

Basically what I want is to make a summary of the columns weights for each combination and the multiply by the observation (represented by the column obs. For example, in the first row I have the combination Germany to Germany so what I want is to sum the weights of the column Weight (119+4=123) and then multiply the result of this sum (123* 1=123) to the respective observation of the column Obs (1) (in the first row). For the second row would be the same the summary of the weight for Germany would be (119+4=123)and this result have to be multiplied by the observation of this row in this case (123* 2=246). In the third row the sum of weights would be (3+2=5) and then multiply this result by the observations for this row (5* 3=15) and so on.

The output that I want is represented by the column x and it would be something like this.

| Country1 | Country2 | Weight | obs | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | Germany | 4 | 1 | 123 |
| Germany | Germany | 119 | 2 | 246 |
| France | Germany | 3 | 3 | 15 |
| France | Germany | 2 | 4 | 20 |
| Italy | France | 1 | 5 | 5 |

Also the formula that im trying to apply is this one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% group_by(Country1) %>%
  mutate(x=sum(Weight)*obs)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   Country1 [3]
  Country1 Country2 Weight   obs     x
  <chr>    <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
1 Germany  Germany       4     1   123
2 Germany  Germany     119     2   246
3 France   Germany       3     3    15
4 France   Germany       2     4    20
5 Italy    France        1     5     5
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Country1 = c("Germany", "Germany", "France", "France", 
"Italy"), Country2 = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"France"), Weight = c(4L, 119L, 3L, 2L, 1L), obs = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also solve it as follows:

```
df1$x <- tapply(df1$Weight, df1$Country1, sum)[df1$Country1] * df1$obs

  Country1 Country2 Weight obs   x
1  Germany  Germany      4   1 123
2  Germany  Germany    119   2 246
3   France  Germany      3   3  15
4   France  Germany      2   4  20
5    Italy   France      1   5   5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, x := sum(Weight) *obs, by = Country1][]
```

-output

```
#   Country1 Country2 Weight obs   x
#1:  Germany  Germany      4   1 123
#2:  Germany  Germany    119   2 246
#3:   France  Germany      3   3  15
#4:   France  Germany      2   4  20
#5:    Italy   France      1   5   5
```

---

Or using `base R` with `ave`

```
df1$x <- with(df1, ave(Weight, Country1, FUN = sum) * obs)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Country1 = c("Germany", "Germany", "France", "France", 
"Italy"), Country2 = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"France"), Weight = c(4L, 119L, 3L, 2L, 1L), obs = 1:5),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```